# How to upload project with mercurial on googlecode?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, google-code

1. I have create a local directory, and made some sub-directories and file in it.
2. registered by project on code.google.com/hosting
3. install Mercurial and did > hg init
4. copied the auto-generated password from google, still dont know for what.

Now how do i upload files my local to the repository on google.
Tired googling a lot, almost all the information is available for SVN users.

Do i have to create a branch on mercurial first. I am sorry if it is too silly, but how do i create one, the site does say anything create or upload or add.

Can anyone please share, how he started/uploaded his project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't created anything big in your local repo yet, the easiest way is the following.

Make a clone of the Google Code repository:

```
hg clone https://your_project.googlecode.com/hg your_local_repo
```

This will create a directory "`your_local_repo`" with a local repository in it. Make your changes here and

```
hg commit -m "Your commit message"
```

to commit the changes to your local repo. Then

```
hg push
```

to push the changes to the repository on GC.

Comment: @balpha-- have you used wiki feature locally for your any of your project.

Comment: @balpha-- have you used wiki feature locally for your any of your project. If yes then is there any wikiSyntax-toolbarAttached-editor available for working on wiki entries.

Comment: No, sorry I haven't, I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read this?

- http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted
- http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialStatus
- http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialFAQ